# Make HTML element inherit events from custom object

Tags: javascript

In the webpage I'm working I have a lot of small images to wich I want to assign the same set of events. Instead of adding them one by one, I thought it would be more elegant if I could make that type of element inherit these events.

What comes to my mind is something like :

```
function InheritEvents(){};

InheritEvents.prototype.onmouseover = function(){...action a..};

InheritEvents.prototype.onmouseout  = function(){...action b..};

var temp = originalHTMLElement.constructor; //(in this case img)

originalHTMLElement.prototype = new InheritEvents();

originalHTMLElement.constructor = temp;
```

a) Am I not disturbing the originalHTMLElement  ?

b) Is it possible to name the custom object property, for example
   ".onmouseover" like in the classic way:
    originalHTMLElement.onmouseover = function()...   ?

c) More conceptual: Is it possible to mix your custom objects with HTML 
   elemenst / DOM nodes  ?

Comment: Have you tried this yet? I'm pretty sure it will not have your desired result. It also seems like a bad idea. There are established ways to attach events to elements. There's no need to reinvent the wheel

Comment: So better one by one:  addEventListener / attachEvent

Comment: You can either do that, or attach the event to a single shared parent and use [event delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate). Of course, if you're using jQuery, it will allow you to carry out either option in a single line of codd.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend against this. It probably wouldn't work anyway, but messing with the prototypes of host objects is, in general, a bad idea.

I don't think there should really be a problem with iterating through the target elements and attaching events to them, but if you don't like that, you can use [event delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("images").onclick = function(e) {
    if (e.target && e.target.classList.contains("clickable")) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      console.log("I've been clicked!");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#images div {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
}
#images div.clickable {
  background-color: red;
}
#images + * {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="images">
    <!-- Pretend that these DIVs are your images -->
    <div></div>
    <div class="clickable"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="clickable"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    Click one of the red images above
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course, if you're using jQuery, the `.on()` method can handle both the "add an event handler to all members of a set" option and the event delegation option in a single line.